# glGetFloat(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview) returns an identity matrix

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to transform 3d point coordinates to the 2d screen coordinates.

But, the problem is when I implemented it and run the program, even though I change the camera position, there was no change on the output. Output generally out of the screen coordinates range even though I can completely see the 3d model(so no chance of any point or triangle to go out of the screen coordinates).

Method that convers the 3d coordinates to 2d ones:

```
public Vector2f get2DFrom3D(float x, float y, float z)
{

    FloatBuffer screen_coords = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
    IntBuffer viewport = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(16);
    FloatBuffer modelview = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    FloatBuffer projection = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);

    GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
    System.out.println("modelview:");
    displayFloatBuffer(modelview);

    GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
    System.out.println("projection:");
    displayFloatBuffer(projection);

    GL11.glGetInteger(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    System.out.println("viewport:");
    displayIntBuffer(viewport);

    boolean result = GLU.gluProject(x, y, z, modelview, projection, viewport, screen_coords);
    if (result)
    {
        System.out.printf("Convert [ %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f ] -> Screen [ %4d %4d ]\n", x, y, z, (int)screen_coords.get(0), (int)(screen_coords.get(3)-screen_coords.get(1)));
        return new Vector2f((int)screen_coords.get(0), (int)(screen_coords.get(3)-screen_coords.get(1)));
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Projection matrix is created via this method and directly loaded into the vertex shader:

```
private void createProjectionMatrix(){
        float aspectRatio = (float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight();
        float y_scale = (float) ((1f / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(FOV / 2f))) * aspectRatio);
        float x_scale = y_scale / aspectRatio;
        float frustum_length = FAR_PLANE - NEAR_PLANE;

        projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        projectionMatrix.m00 = x_scale;
        projectionMatrix.m11 = y_scale;
        projectionMatrix.m22 = -((FAR_PLANE + NEAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
        projectionMatrix.m23 = -1;
        projectionMatrix.m32 = -((2 * NEAR_PLANE * FAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
        projectionMatrix.m33 = 0;
    }
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

void main(void) {

    vec4 worldPosition = transformationMatrix * vec4(position, 1);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * worldPosition;

}
```

Renderer:

```
public void render(Entity entity, int displayMode) {

    RawModel model = entity.getModel();

    shader.start();
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVaoID());
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    Matrix4f transformationMatrix = Maths.createTransformationMatrix(entity.getPosition(), entity.getRotX(),
            entity.getRotY(), entity.getRotZ(), entity.getScale());
    shader.loadTransformationMatrix(transformationMatrix);

    GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVertexAmount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    shader.stop();
}
```

Then, I debug the code and see that:

```
GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelView);
GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
```

These lines are just not taking real matrix values that I defined. They are just order 4 identity matrices. Then, I searched for glMatrixMode to set that matrices or set gl_ModelViewMatrix, but it turns out that the opengl version I use is not supporting those anymore.

So, I think the problem is I somehow related to those variables and I somehow need to set them. Last but not least, here is the output for the get2DFrom3D method:

```
modelview:
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 
projection:
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 
viewport:
0 0 1209 891 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

I think only viewport is correct but modelview and projection matrices are looking like they're not loading the values calculated for them.

Note: I'm currently using lwjgl 2.9.3.

Comment: Welcome to SO!. **1)** Please, provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  **2)** Don't post a link, better include the code  **3)** Forget old OpenGL and use modern version >= 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem and it works fine. Here is my new get2DFrom3D method:

```
public Vector2f get2DFrom3D(float x, float y, float z)
{
    FloatBuffer screen_coords = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
    IntBuffer viewport = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(16);
    FloatBuffer modelview = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);  
    FloatBuffer projection = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);

    Matrix4f modelviewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    Matrix4f transformationMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    Matrix4f.mul(transformationMatrix
            , Maths.createViewMatrix(camera)
            , modelviewMatrix);

    modelviewMatrix.store(modelview);
    modelview.rewind();

    projectionMatrix.store(projection);
    projection.rewind();

    GL11.glGetInteger(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

    boolean result = GLU.gluProject(x, y, z, modelview, projection, viewport, screen_coords);

    if (result)
    {
        Vector2f vector = new Vector2f((int)screen_coords.get(0), (int)(screen_coords.get(1)));
        return vector;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Instead of using glGetFloat method to get modelview and projection matrices. I instead used the matrices I already created in my other classes and pass those matrices as parameters. Then, I convert the matrices to buffers so that I can use them. After rewinding them, I finally be able to get the correct screen coordinates of a point from gluProject.

Even though problem is solved, I still don't know why these lines did't work:

```
  GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
    System.out.println("modelview:");
    displayFloatBuffer(modelview);

    GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
```